# View Sensor list on android device

Tags: android, list, view, sensors

I am a new to Android development and I would like to create an application which shows the list of sensors on my Android device.

I tried to find this but without the success.

Can you please help me.

Here is the solution how to do this:

```
///////////////  List of Sensors  //////////////////////////////
listeCapteurs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

SensorManager sensorManager=
(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> listSensor=
sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

List<String> listSensorType = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i<listSensor.size(); i++)
{
listSensorType.add(listSensor.get(listSensor.size()-1-i).getName());
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`SensorManager.getSensorList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList(int)).

Comment: The problem is that i know how to get the list with the SensorManager.getSensorList() but i don't know how to view this list on my device. I think that i have to modify the xml file but don't know how...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SensorManager mgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> sensors = mgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
    Log.d("Sensors", "" + sensor.getName());
}
```

my output is:

```
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): BMA150 3-axis Accelerometer
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): AK8973 3-axis Magnetic field sensor
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): AK8973 Orientation sensor
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): CM3602 Proximity sensor
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): CM3602 Light sensor
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): Gravity Sensor
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): Linear Acceleration Sensor
10-28 21:34:03.224: D/Sensors(27760): Rotation Vector Sensor
```

Comment: Thank you Craigy, the code seems to work but can you please help me wit hthe xml file because i have nothing it the screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it answers your question, and post a new question about your xml issue

Comment: Here is the link to my new question...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029842/view-the-android-sensor-list-with-xml

Comment: More generally, 
    '{
        Log.d("Sensors", "" + sensor.toString());
    }' has the advantage that you should get more information about each sensor.