# Check what sensors an Android device has?

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

So I want to create a list with all available sensor types on an Android device, so in a timer I can get the current value from all available sensors.

I have this currently:

```
List<Sensor> availableSensors;

public void getAllSensors() {
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    SensorManager sensorMngr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorMngr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
        if (manager.hasSystemFeature(/*Not sure what to do here*/ sensor)) {
            availableSensors.add(sensor);
        }
    }
}
```

I added a comment on the bit I'm unsure on. `hasSystemFeature` seems to be expecting a string, but when I try parsing it `sensor.getName()` or even `sensor`, I'm getting no results.

How do you check if a device has a sensor type, when that type is stored in a variable? I'm sure the answer is really simple, but I just can't work it out. I need to future proof this code, so I can't use a switch to work it out.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7936422/883012

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can see the list of available sensors like this:

```
public void printAllSensors() {
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    SensorManager sensorMngr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorMngr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
        // debug or print the follwoing
        sensor.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: You call your method `getAllSensors()` but don't return the list of sensors? Instead you add them to some member variable which you don't even initialize? That is just really bad design...

Comment: Well its a bad one. Someone who is just learning programming will come along see this and implement it 1:1 because he just doesn't know any better. Do you really want that to happen? Just think of all the `NullPointerException` questions this could spawn simply because you didn't initialize the `List`. What's wrong with directly returning the `List` you get from the `SensorManager`?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I'm sorry for confusing and I should have checked it.

Comment: I feel like some of these criticisms are worded in unnecessarily harsh ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (replace TYPE_ACCELEROMETER with whatever type you want to check):

```
SensorManager sensorMngr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
Sensor sensor = sensorMngr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if (sensor != null) {
  // sensor exists and you have permission to access it
}
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getDefaultSensor(int))